# Unresolved reference ( im new)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and on this lesson I don't acutally know what I'm doing wrong:

```
weight = 8.4

# Ground Shipping

if weight <= 2:
 ground_cost = weight * 1.50 + 20

elif weight <= 6:
  ground_cost = weight * 3.00 + 20

elif weight <= 10:
  ground_cost = weight * 4.00 + 20

else:
  print(ground_cost = (weight * 4.75 + 20))
  print(ground_cost)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` block looks like it could be wrong. You can certainly assign and evaluate in the same statement in modern Python but you would use the walrus operator `:=` rather than `=`.

Additionally, you probably want to print the ground cost for *all* cases, not just the last.

In other words, something like this:

```py
weight = 8.4

# Ground Shipping

if weight <= 2:
    ground_cost = weight * 1.50 + 20
elif weight <= 6:
    ground_cost = weight * 3.00 + 20
elif weight <= 10:
    ground_cost = weight * 4.00 + 20
else:
    ground_cost = weight * 4.75 + 20

print(ground_cost)
```